# Qt Multi-threaded Multi-client TCP server socket->write() issue

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, sockets, tcp

I have a Qt GUI/console application for my TCP server. The server has an array of threads each containing a connection to a different client.

If you have done multi-threaded TCP servers before then you would probably have seen a client thread with a run function something like.

```
    void ClientThread::run()
{

    //thread starts here
    socket = new QTcpSocket();
    if(!socket->setSocketDescriptor(this->socketDescriptor))
    {
        emit error(socket->error());
        return;
    }

    connect(socket,SIGNAL(readyRead()),this,SLOT(readyRead()),Qt::DirectConnection);
    connect(socket,SIGNAL(disconnected()),this,SLOT(disconnected()),Qt::DirectConnection);
    connect(socket,SIGNAL(readyRead()),this,SLOT(readyRead()),Qt::DirectConnection);

    qDebug() << socketDescriptor << " Client Connected";
    emit threadDataOut(QString::number(socketDescriptor) + " Client Connected");

    exec();
}
```

And with a readRead() function a ClientThread SLOT that receives from a readyRead() QTcpSocket SIGNAL I assume.

```
void ClientThread::readyRead()
{
    QByteArray Data = socket->readAll();

     qDebug() << socketDescriptor << "Recived: " << Data;

     //send data on to be displayed on GUI
     emit threadDataOut(Data);

     //Echo data back to client for testing purposes
     socket->write(Data);
}
```

The data is received and is echoed back no problems.

However I want to only send data that is passed from the user interface to the server to the client thread to a ClientThread::transmit(QByteArray Data) SLOT function.

```
void ClientThread::transmit(QByteArray Data)
{
    qDebug()<<"Sent: "<< Data <<" to "<< this->socketDescriptor;

    socket->write(Data);
}
```

So the correct client receives the data/message, but the server gives the error

QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.
(Parent is QNativeSocketEngine(0x1b83e520), parent's thread is ClientThread(0x1b840da0), current thread is QThread(0x983390)

From this point on the server is unable to receive any data sent by that particular client. For some reason the connection continues to work in the other direction.

However if another data message is sent to that client the client receives it twice and if another data message is sent a third time the client receives message 3 times etc.

Can anyone explain what may be going on here? and More importantly what would be an appropriate solution?

Note: I have been testing on a windows computer using telnet clients on the local loop back 127.0.0.1
I've refrained posting all my code for now, as I believe the problem is evident in what I have given thus far.

Comment: *as I believe the problem is evident in what I have given thus far* if the problem is evident, why are you asking the question?

Comment: @sergeya Presumably because for OP the solution isn't

Comment: Not obvious from the partial code, but this suggests the socket is being accessed from more than one thread.

Comment: Why are you using threads in the first place? And it looks like you're adding slots to QThread subclasses, and forcing connection types... i.e. all the things that you should never ever do. Remove the threads and switch to a normal event driven design.

Comment: @peppe .. I agree that the design isn't very elegant, but do you have any reference to documentation that support your claim about not adding slots to QThread subclasses, I'd be interested in that. And suggesting an event driven model rather than a thread based one is highly dependent on the individual program. The usual argument that threads are too difficult to XXXX (fill in) isn't a very valid one IMO.

Comment: Threads are too easy to screw up, not too difficult to understand. Event driven is difficult to understand (that's why people don't "naturally" go with it) but also difficult to screw up. Add QObject mechanics on top of threading and the disaster is served. See https://wiki.qt.io/Threads_Events_QObjects and similar documentation.

Comment: Why are you using threads in the first place? - @peppe Good question. For my application I need to be able to send and receive asynchronously. For cases where the sever and clients are sending and receiving data at the same time.

So if I can't/shouldn't add slots to my QThread subclass ClientThread, how would I be able to send any data to "transmit" through the socket in my ClientThread's?

Comment: You can make a class "MySocket" inheriting from `QTcpSocket`, define a slot "writeSlot" which simply call "write" and then use `QMetaObject::invokeMethod(mySocket, "writeSlot", Qt::QueuedConnection, Q_ARG(QByteArray, data)` from the main thread (in your transmit() method in this case) and you should be ok. I also tried to do that but went back to the event driven model as I have less than ten clients and I don't want complexity when it's not necessary. I think threads are not necessary until you have at least hundreds of clients and/or a lot of traffic.